# How to solve 'Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled' in Laravel 6?

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, ecmascript-6, laravel-6

I inserted some JS files with classes into my Laravel project today, and upon running `npm run dev` I came across this error. I spent many hours looking for a solution, but none of the ones I found worked for me.

Tried to install `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`, but that changed nothing.
Reinstalled the latest version of Laravel Mix, that did nothing.
Tried to change some things around in package.json, webpack.config.js and some babel config, but that resulted in more errors about packages not found and whatnot.